# How do I reference Source-Layer in a pg_tileserv service?

Tags: style, vector-tiles, pg-tileserv, maputnik

this is the first time i'm trying to style a vectortile-service so i might be thinking completely wrong, but ....

I have set up a pg_tileserv that shows all geometries. when I then want to specify the style for this in eg Maputnik, I must specify "Source Layer" in the service but I do not understand what it is I must specify there ...

json description of the service as below, where can I find the name of "Source Layer"?

Json the description of the service:

```
{"id":"navet.avdelning","schema":"navet","name":"avdelning","properties":[{"name":"objectid","type":"int4","description":""},{"name":"publicid","type":"varchar","description":""},{"name":"beteckning","type":"varchar","description":""},{"name":"malklass","type":"varchar","description":""},{"name":"agoslag","type":"varchar","description":""},{"name":"utvecklingsklass","type":"varchar","description":""},{"name":"html","type":"text","description":""},{"name":"uppdateradden","type":"timestamp","description":""},{"name":"gdb_geomattr_data","type":"bytea","description":""}],"geometrytype":"Geometry","center":[17.78407344385394,61.927558022338715],"bounds":[12.220784431419643,55.89765459428104,23.34736245628824,67.9574614503964],"minzoom":0,"maxzoom":22,"tileurl":"http://localhost:7800/navet.avdelning/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf"}
```

Json for the layer in Maputnik:

```
{
  "id": "skog",
  "type": "fill",
  "source": "navet_avd",
  "maxzoom": 20,
  "source-layer": "?????"
}
```

Comment: I do not know how I failed this the other day. It was ID in the vectortileservice that would be used as a "source-layer"  {
      "id": "skog",
      "type": "fill",
      "source": "navet_avd",
      "source-layer": "navet.avdelning",
      "paint": {"fill-color": "rgba(202, 224, 36, 1)"}
    }